# Why can I not assign a method reference directly to a variable of Object type?

Tags: java, syntax, java-8

Simple question about `java-8` syntax. Why does `JLS-8` restrict such expressions like:

```
Object of_ref = Stream::of;  // compile-time error
```

and allows only something like:

```
java.util.function.Function of_ref = Stream::of;
Object obj = of_ref; // compiles ok
```

?

Comment: In your first uncompilable snippet what would you expect to be stored in `of_ref`? What would be the concrete type of the instance referenced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the target type of a method reference or a lambda expression should be a functional interface. Based on that only, runtime will create an instance of a class providing implementation of the given functional interface. Think of lambdas or method references as `abstract` concept. Assigning it to a functional interface type gives it a concrete meaning.

Moreover, a particular lambda or method reference, can have multiple functional interfaces as its target type. For example, consider the following lamda:

```
int x = 5;
FunctionalInterface func = (x) -> System.out.println(x);
```

This lambda is a `Consumer` of `x`. In addition to that, any interface with a single abstract method with following signature:

```
public abstract void xxx(int value);
```

can be used as target type. So, which interface would you want runtime to implement, if you assign the lambda to `Object` type? That is why you've to explicitly provide a functional interface as target type.

Now, once you got a functional interface reference holding an instance, you can assign it to any super reference (including `Object`)

Comment: Thanks, but it sounds for me alogical: I can convert my `obj` back to `Function` and invoke `apply()`, so we I can not do this direct when retrieving method reference?

Comment: @Andremoniy To convert `obj` back to `Function`, you've to first create an `object` right? What would be the type of that `object`?

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand your logic.

Comment: The problem is the compiler does not know to which functional interface to convert the provided lambda expression or method reference.  For example, the method ref `String::isEmpty` is compatible with `Function<String,Boolean>`, `Predicate<String>`, and many others.  The compiler learns the desired type of the function by looking at the assignment context; `Object` does not provide enough information here.  This is not unlike why you cannot say `new List<String>()`; the compiler does not know which implementation of `List` you want.

Comment: Note that adding a cast is enough for the compiler to infer the correct functional interface to implement: `Object obj = (Function<?, ?>) Stream::of`

Answer (score 9):

`Object` is not a functional interface and a method reference can only be assigned to a functional interface. See for example [JLS #15.13.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2)

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

Comment: Thanks, but I ask why I can not directly assign this reference to `Object`?

Comment: Because `Object`, represented as `T` in the JLS quote, is not a functional interface type.

Answer (score 8):

The key point is that *there are no "function types"* in Java. A lambda expression doesn't have a "type" by itself -- it can be typed to *any* functional interface whose sole method's signature matches the lambda. Therefore, a lambda's type is based on the type provided by its context. You must provide a functional interface as the context for it to get a type.

It is instructive to consider the same issue but for anonymous classes. Although there are implementation differences between lambdas and anonymous classes, semantically, lambdas are essentially equivalent to a subset of anonymous classes, and a lambda expression can always be converted to an equivalent anonymous class creation expression.

When you write:

```
Function<T, Stream<T>> of_ref = Stream::of;
```

it is equivalent to something like the following using anonymous classes:

```
Function<T, Stream<T>> of_ref = new Function<T, Stream<T>>() {
    Stream<T> apply(T t) {
        return Stream.of(t);
    }
};
```

Now consider

```
Object of_ref = Stream::of;
```

what is the equivalent with anonymous classes?

```
Object of_ref = new [**What goes here?**]() {
    [**What method signature goes here?**] {
        return Stream.of(t);
    }
};
```

You see why it doesn't make sense -- we don't know what type to use as the base class of the anonymous class.

Comment: Ok! This means that it is just syntactic sugar, yes?

Comment: @Andremoniy: Well, it depends on how you define "syntactic sugar". In some cases some conversion is necessary (e.g. `this` in lambda is equivalent to `OuterClass.this`, not `this`, in an anonymous class), and there are some behavioral differences, like two anonymous class objects are distinct (`!=`), but two lambdas may not be. But for the most part you can think of it as a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7):

**You can!** You just need to give the compiler a little more information so it knows what functional interface the method reference should implement:

```
Object obj = (Function<?, ?>) Stream::of;
```

Method references and lambda expressions work by using *type inference* to determine what interface the anonymous class they create should implement. Without the `Function` cast, the only type Java has to work with is `Object` - which most certainly isn't a functional interface (an interface with only one non-static non-default method). Explicitly casting the method reference expression to a `Function` provides the missing type information we need, then we can assign the `Object` field to the function because `Function` is a subtype of `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is a purely academical question, since I can't see any real-life use case for this. Nevertheless, I am pretty sure that it has to do with `Stream::of` being a lambda expression. You could also not do this:

```
Object of_ref = list -> Stream.of(list);
```

I speculate that an accurate return type tells the compiler which [FunctionalInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) it being used.  Without this information it is impossible for the compiler to resolve the Lambda expression correctly and unambiguously.