# Android/Java - remove method reference from List

Tags: java, android, method-reference

I have a array list of method references (object::method) where I insert some methods when the user clicks a button. The problem is that I also need to remove some specific method references at some point.

If I use list.remove(object::method) the method is not removed because the lambda object::method has another ID every time I use it. I want each object::method to be removable so I need a way to get the same lambda ID for each object-method-pair.

Is there a way to accomplish this or do I have to manually keep track of every ID I added so I can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29082592/2657100

> the target type of a method reference or a lambda expression should be a functional interface. Based on that only, runtime will create an instance of a class providing implementation of the given functional interface.

Try adding in a list the same method reference twice. You'll see that you'll have two different objects, and calling `equals` on one another will probably return `false`.

So you will have a hard time managing instances of functional interfaces without an auxiliary structure like an ID or a reflective `Method` instance, or something like that.